How to handle web.xml with multiple exact matches?
I need to create a rest service with multiple exact matches but I don't know how to handle it within web.xml and resource classes. How to create a resource class that is mapped to an exact <url-pattern> match? If there was only one exact match I could use @Path("/") but that won't work here. The application I'm working on has to have few exact matches and I cannot use /* pattern as there are also other filters that should handle them. I'm using Jersey 2.42.
Current sample implementation that doesn't work.
web.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>main-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.test</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>main-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/foo</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/bar</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

/foo resource:
@Path("/foo")
public class FooResource {
    @GET
    public String foo() {
        return "Foo";
    }
}

/bar resource:
@Path("/bar")
public class BarResource {
    @GET
    public String bar() {
        return "Bar";
    }
}


Have you tried giving each resource its own mapping?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>main-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.test</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>main-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/foo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>main-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/bar</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>


It doesn't work.
The value of @Path is appended to the url-pattern in servlet mapping. So in this configuration when the servlet handles exact matches on "/foo" it tries to find appropriate resource but fails to do so, as the FooResource is actually mapped to path "/foo/foo".

It seems to be an issue with the servlet mappings and resource annotations. Can you please try updating the  below in the web.xml
/*
Verify the resource package name once.

I cannot use the /* url-pattern as explained in the question.

You can use @PreMatching filter. The filter is used before the URI is matched, and you can replace the URI with a new one. Something like:
@PreMatching
public class RedirectFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        URI uri = requestContext.getUriInfo().getRequestUri();
        uri = URI.create(uri.toString().replace("foo", "foo/foo").replace("bar", "bar/bar"));
        requestContext.setRequestUri(uri);
    }
}

